# How can I ensure async code from an imported module finishes before the current module's code starts?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await, promise, require

I'd like to first connect to MongoDB via `mongoose.connect()` in Module A, then use this connection to send requests in Module B.

The problem is that `mongoose.connect()` is an async function, so the requests in Module B are sent before the connection from Module A is fully established, causing them to timeout.

How can I solve the above issue?

**Minimal reproducible example:**

app.js  (a.k.a. "Module A", where the connection is established)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')


const mongoURL = //replace this with your own Mongo URL

const connectAndReturnApp = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(mongoURL, {
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useFindAndModify: false
    })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  const app = 'thisIsJustAPlaceHolderForExport'
  return app
}

module.exports = connectAndReturnApp()
```

index.js (a.k.a. "Module B", where Module A's connection is used to send requests to MongoDB)

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const app = require('./app')


const exampleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  author: String
})
const Example = mongoose.model('Example', exampleSchema)

const exampleOne = new Example({
  title: 'Don Quixote',
  author: 'M. Cervantes'
})

const main = async () => {  
  try {
    const res = await exampleOne.save()  
    console.log(res)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
  mongoose.connection.close()
}

main() //This leads to timeout when called =,(
```

Comment: I'd highly recommend exporting *functions* (which have no side-effects until run) rather than objects - they make managing dependencies much easier, especially in large projects. You could have "Module A" import the "Module B" as a function, then call it after the `.connect`. Another option is to have "Module B" import "Module A"'s Promise, then call `.then` on it and put all of Module B's code into the `.then` callback.

Comment: @CertainPerformance This is a very nice solution to my issue. However, I now have another similar, related problem, this time related to Jest rather than import/exports. Please see if you can help with this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66193832/async-beforeall-does-not-finish-before-beforeeach-is-called#66193832