# Async beforeAll() does not finish before beforeEach() is called

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise, jestjs, control-flow

In Jest, `beforeAll()` is supposed to run before `beforeEach()`.

The problem is that when I use an async callback for `beforeAll()`, Jest doesn't wait for the callback to finish before going on to `beforeEach()`.

How can I force Jest to wait for an async `beforeAll()` callback to finish before proceeding to `beforeEach()`?

#### Minimal reproducible example

tests/myTest.test.js

```
const connectToMongo = require('../my_async_callback')    

// This uses an async callback.
beforeAll(connectToMongo) 

// This is entered before the beforeAll block finishes. =,(
beforeEach(() => { 
  console.log('entered body of beforeEach')  
})

test('t1'), () => {
  expect(1).toBe(1)
}
test('t2'), () => {
  expect(2+2).toBe(4)
}
test('t3'), () => {
  expect(3+3+3).toBe(9)
}
```

my_async_callback.js

```
const connectToMongo = async () => {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI, { 
      useNewUrlParser: true, 
      useUnifiedTopology: true, 
      useFindAndModify: false, 
      useCreateIndex: true 
    })
    console.log('Connected to MongoDB')
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error connecting to MongoDB: ${err.message}`)
  }
}

module.exports = connectToMongo
```

**UPDATE:** As the accepted answer helpfully points out, Jest actually does wait for `beforeAll` to finish first, except in the case of a broken Promise chain or a timeout. So, the premise of my question is false. My `connectToMongo` function was timing out, and simply increasing the Jest timeout solved the problem.

Comment: This is expected behaviour of Jest. The names of beforeAll and beforeEach suggest only that they will be evaluated before all and each tests, the order of execution is not guaranteed. If you want In this case the problem is irrelevant because it's not Mongo but Mongoose. Mongoose chains connection promise internally, you can skip waiting for a connection. Notice that `catch (err)` is a mistake because it suppresses an error (though this won't prevent beforeAll from proceeding).

Comment: @EstusFlask "In this case the problem is irrelevant because it's not Mongo but Mongoose[...]" Yet, the DB requests time out when using separate `beforeAll` and `beforeEach` *despite working otherwise*. That is, they work when I connect in `beforeEach` (as ugly as that is) or omit Jest altogether. What could explain this behavior, if not Mongoose execution being order-dependent?

Comment: @EstusFlask Also, could you please elaborate on "Notice that catch (err) is a mistake because it suppresses an error."? What would be the ideal way of catching this error, then?

Comment: An error should be caught by a caller (Jest in this case), so there should be no `catch`, or at least rethrow an error. I'd expect it to work without async..await in beforeAll but I can't confirm this. Any way, for such order you may want custom wrapper over beforeEach, something like, `let mongoProm; let beforeEachMongo = async (cb) => { mongoProm = mongoProm || mongoose.connection(...); await mongoProm; return cb() }`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The problem is that when I use an async callback for `beforeAll()`, Jest doesn't wait for the callback to finish before going on to `beforeEach()`.
>
> How can I force Jest to wait for an async `beforeAll()` callback to finish before proceeding to `beforeEach()`?

### TLDR

The short answer is that Jest **does** wait for an async `beforeAll()` callback to finish before proceeding to `beforeEach()`.

This means that if `beforeEach()` is running before something that should run in `beforeAll()` then the Promise chain must be broken or the `beforeAll` function is timing out.

---

### Queue Runner in Jest

All of the `beforeAll`, `beforeEach`, `test`, `afterEach`, `afterAll` functions associated with a test are collected in `queueableFns` and are chained [on these lines in queueRunner.ts](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/615084195ae1ae61ddd56162c62bbdda17587569/packages/jest-jasmine2/src/queueRunner.ts#L92-L95):

```
  const result = options.queueableFns.reduce(
    (promise, fn) => promise.then(() => mapper(fn)),
    Promise.resolve(),
  );
```

So Jest starts with a resolved Promise and chains every function, in order, to the Promise chain with `.then`.

---

This behavior can be seen with the following test:

```
const order = [];

// first beforeAll with async function
beforeAll(async () => {
  order.push(1);
  await new Promise((resolve) => { setTimeout(resolve, 1000); });
  order.push(2);
});

// first beforeEach with done callback
beforeEach(done => {
  order.push(4);
  setTimeout(() => {
    order.push(6);
    done();
  }, 1000);
  order.push(5);
});

// second beforeEach
beforeEach(() => {
  order.push(7);
});

// second beforeAll
beforeAll(() => {
  order.push(3);
});

it("should run in order", () => {
  expect(order).toEqual([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]);  // SUCCESS!
});
```

---

### Broken Promise Chain

If `beforeEach` is running before something that should run in `beforeAll` then it is possible the Promise chain is broken:

```
const order = [];

// does not return Promise and will break the Promise chain
const func = () => {
  setTimeout(() => { order.push(2); }, 1000);
}

const asyncFunc = async () => {
  order.push(1);
  await func();  // doesn't actually wait for 2 to be pushed
  order.push(3);
}

beforeAll(asyncFunc);

beforeEach(() => {
  order.push(4);
});

it("should run in order", () => {
  expect(order).toEqual([1, 2, 3, 4]);  // FAIL: [1, 3, 4]
});
```

---

### Timeout

...or there is a timeout (note that the timeout will be reported by Jest in the output):

```
const order = [];

jest.setTimeout(100);  // 100ms timeout

const asyncFunc = async () => {
  order.push(1);
  await new Promise(resolve => { setTimeout(resolve, 1000); });  // times out
  order.push(2);
}

beforeAll(asyncFunc);

beforeEach(() => {
  order.push(3);
});

it("should run in order", () => {
  expect(order).toEqual([1, 2, 3]);  // FAIL: [1, 3] and Timeout error
});
```

Comment: Excellent! It turns out my `connectToMongo` function was simply timing out since my connection was slow. Increasing the `testTimeout` property in Jest solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If there is async function and callback you can call done. if you want to pass callback inside the async function you are free!

Let me show you;

```
beforeAll(async (done) => {
  await connectToMongo().catch(done) // if there is error it finish with error payload
  done(); // it says i am finish. also you can use it on your callback function to say i am done.
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I've tried both `done` and returning a Promise, as recommended in the Jest docs (https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous). Jest is still entering `beforeEach` before the connection in `beforeAll` is established.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when upgrading to angular 14. Solution was to upgrade `zone.js` to `0.11.8`. Found solution here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/45476#issuecomment-1195153212

Answer (score -1):

`connectToMongo` function is an async function, not a `async callback` (async function with a function as a parameter ???)

`beforeEach` will be called when `beforeAll` is finished, and it still works well.

`beforeAll(connectToMongo)`  will be done right after you call it, this means, it will not wait until the db connect success.

Just wait until `connectToMongo` done and continue:

```
beforeAll(async () => { // async function
    await connectToMongo() // wait until connected to db
})
```

Comment: connectToMongo is a *callback* and is also `async`. Unless it uses params that can interefere with Jest's `done` (it doesn't), it's perfectly ok to use it as `beforeAll(connectToMongo)`. *will be done right after you call it* - it won't. It would be if it were `beforeAll(connectToMongo())`, but it isn't, and this is not how callbacks are used.

Comment: As Estus says, this answer uses a wrong definition of callback as of this writing. (For the correct definition, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing#async_callbacks). It also doesn't solve my problem since `connectToMongo` is already async, so the provided code does nothing more than what I wrote.